# How can I resolve certificate issues in Eucalyptus?

Tags: eucalyptus

I have recently installed eucalyptus on a Ubuntu 10.04. Everything works fine until I get to the user interface. Whenever I try to get to the store tab I get the following error:

```
Error 60: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

I have been doing some research and tried to update the certificate, make changes to the /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imagestore/lib/fetch.py but none of these solutions worked.

I am really stuck and do not know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help resolve the issue on Ubuntu and I suspect the Euca version involved is way out date. If you are willing to work on CentOS then you've got two great options

1. FastStart - this is an awesome bundle of Eucalyptus and CentOS. I use this to spin up a new cloud after each release, including the pre-release of 3.3. Total time to new cloud is roughly 35 minutes.
   http://www.eucalyptus.com/download/faststart
2. Package downloads - This is your standard install method and the only option to pick if you're trying to build a large cloud.
   http://www.eucalyptus.com/download/eucalyptus

BTW - if you are looking to build a large cloud I also recommend you check out the Reference Architectures. These are Eucalyptus deployment blueprints based on lots of real-world, customer environments. http://eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus-cloud/reference-architectures

If you have other questions, I hope we see you on IRC. It's the #eucalyptus channel on freenode: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=eucalyptus

Hope this helps